# Refer Sheet that User-input named

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

After running macro and generate data in this Original sheet, I prompt the user to name that Original sheet using below code.

```
oriSheet = InputBox("Please Name the Sheet?", vbOKCancel)
If oriSheet = False Or oriSheet = "" Then
MsgBox "Invalid Name"
Exit Sub
Else
ActiveSheet.Name = oriSheet
End If
oriSheet = ""
```

Then I run another sub, to take the oriSheet just now for filtering.
Is it possible to refer that worksheet using variable?
Because I don't seem to get there with error "subscript out of range" in below code.

```
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("oriSheet")
Set newsht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2")
```

I took away the double quotes thinking because of them, oriSheet does not be interpreted, like other programming language. But it's still not working.

I figured it might be easy, but I had spent hours on this.
I went on Google, there is saying goes "There is two ways to refer worksheet, by index (but Idk the index) and by Name (but Idk the name too?)"

Comment: You need to set the reference to the sheet before renaming it, e.g. `Set WS = Activesheet  ... WS.Name = oriSheet`.

Comment: You should try this. `Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(oriSheet)` since oriSheet is a string itself. Of course you need to avoid from resetting it (`oriSheet = " "`) at the end of the other procedure and also the variable (and preferably Subs) should be `Public`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your first macro to store `oriSheet` into another variable at the end of it;

```
Public oriSheetRecorder As String
oriSheet = InputBox("Please Name the Sheet?", vbOKCancel)
If oriSheet = False Or oriSheet = "" Then
MsgBox "Invalid Name"
Exit Sub
Else
ActiveSheet.Name = oriSheet
On Error Goto Errorhandler
oriSheetRecorder = oriSheet
oriSheet = ""
End If

Errorhandler:
MsgBox "Name of the active sheet is " , ActiveSheet.Name, "It is Invalid Name or an error has happened"
Exit Sub
```

Then in your second `Sub` have this:

```
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(oriSheetRecorder)
Set newsht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2")
```

The reason that your code doesn't work right now is that because you clear `oriSheet` at this line: `oriSheet = ""` so later you cannot refer to it. Also, you don't need (should not) put `"` around a variable. `double-quote` in excel is for distinguishing between texts and commands and variables. `oriSheet` is a variable which is a string by its definition so it never needs `"` around it to be identified as text.

Comment: Hi @Masoud, thank you. I've noticed that you added a few lines on Errorhandler. Then I found out no matter what name I input, I would get the error :Invalid name , but the sheet with the "invalid name" will still be created without prompting me for another input? 
May I also know, is it possible to rename the sheet2 to the oriSheetRecorder like just replacing it? (because from Google, I see that the default is creating another version of it by automatically name it as "oriSheetRecorder 2"). Or you would like me to add this to my original question? Thanks again.

Comment: @ExcelNovice add it to your original question. I will think about it but as you mentioned it is set to add `2` and make another one and not replacing it. Probably you need to remove/rename the first one and then change the name to `oriSheet`.

Comment: Hi @Masoud, I am able to delete and rename sheet by ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(oriSheetRecorder ).Delete ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2").Name = oriSheetRecorder ! thanks +1 ! See you around